# select sum different columns grouped by another column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have been trying to calculate the total price per "BESTELLING_ID". But I dont know where to start. Grouping on bestelling_id doesn`t seem to work. Here you can see the result of the query where I want to sum the value of the calculation per "BESTELLING_ID". I have been trying to look at other questions but I cant seem to relate the answers to my question. I want to use this for a chart that shows personal order value of per orders. Thanks in advance.

```
BESTELLING_ID   NAAM    ((P.PRIJS)*(R5.GEWICHT/100))
1              ui                    .25
1              pindakaas              1.7
22             Broccoli               1
22             Rijst                  1
```

```
select   b.bestelling_id ,p.naam, ((p.prijs)* (r5.gewicht/100)) 
   from  relation_6 r6
     join bestellingregel br on br.dieet_dieet_id= r6.dieet_id
     join bestelling b on br.bestelling_id=b.bestelling_id
     join relation_5 r5 on r5.recept_recept_id= r6.recept_id
     join product p on p.product_id = r5.product_product_id
   where p.winkelbeheer_winkelbeheer_id=2
   order by b.datum
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 select   
      a.col1 as BESTELLING_ID,sum(a.col3) as Total_Price
 from (      
  SELECT b.bestelling_id col1, p.naam  col2, ( (p.prijs) * (r5.gewicht / 100))  col3
    FROM relation_6 r6
         JOIN bestellingregel br ON br.dieet_dieet_id = r6.dieet_id
         JOIN bestelling b ON br.bestelling_id = b.bestelling_id
         JOIN relation_5 r5 ON r5.recept_recept_id = r6.recept_id
         JOIN product p ON p.product_id = r5.product_product_id
   WHERE p.winkelbeheer_winkelbeheer_id = 2
ORDER BY b.datum ) a
group by a.col1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I`ll have to try this out with an easier query to see how this actually works. But for now this will help me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery, just a `group by`:

```
select b.bestelling_id, sum((p.prijs)* (r5.gewicht/100)) 
from relation_6 r6 join
     bestellingregel br
     on br.dieet_dieet_id = r6.dieet_id join
     bestelling b
     on br.bestelling_id = b.bestelling_id join
     relation_5 r5
     on r5.recept_recept_id = r6.recept_id join
     product p
     on p.product_id = r5.product_product_id
where p.winkelbeheer_winkelbeheer_id = 2
group by b.bestelling_id;
```

You may be able to include `p.naam` in the `select` and `group by`, assuming that there is only one name per `bestselling_id`.